# Are API questions on topic or off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I sent someone over here from Stack Overflow to ask this question:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8965/whats-the-reliability-of-google-chart-api-service-closed

First off, I'm sorry.  I'm not trying to make more work for people, honest. :)

The reason why I sent them over here was because the question seemed to be more about the service itself, rather than how to program with the service.  Basically, it didn't seem like a programming question.

Are questions about API's on topic or off topic?

Here's the SO version of the question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101428/whats-the-reliability-of-google-chart-api-service

Other examples:

- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8939/twitter-api-and-retweets-closed
- Questions asking if an API is available:

  - https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5916/api-to-build-googlestreet-like-photo-maps
  - https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5569/is-there-an-api-for-searching-only-recently-indexed-webpages

Comment: The fact that it deals with an API means it's at least partly programming related. We still haven't specified in the FAQ if API questions are allowed or not, so once we figure this out, we will update the FAQ. I changed this question a bit to reflect that.

Comment: It's an API question, but it was about the reliability and stability of the API, not about programming with the API.  That was my reason for sending it over here.  (I included the SO link to the question because the webapps question appears to have been deleted already.)

Comment: It sounds similar to the questions asking if an API is available, and whatever we decide on should probably be applied to both.

Comment: Right, but the reliability of the API directly affects the reliability of the app that is using that API, which is a programming problem. The only people who are going to be able to judge whether an API is reliable is other developers who have attempted to use it. There's not going to necessarily be a direct correlation between a web app and its API. The audience for the former is here; the latter on StackOverflow.

Comment: That makes sense.  Appreciate the insights.

Comment: @Senseful I doubt you guys will accept API question (searching for "api" yields about 50% closed questions), which I personally regret. SO is of great help if you don't know how to e.g. send a GET request in Java, but issues specific to a particular webapp don't seem to hit the right audience there.

Answer (score 5):

Taking a summary from the comments.

Anything dealing with the API means it is programming related.
Anything dealing with the reliability of the API directly affects the reliability of the app that is using that API, which is a programming problem.

Comment: Related: [Where can I ask a question about developing web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4685)