# Why would this question on Google App Engines be off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Question: [monetizing a google app engine product](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/237440/15162).

ChrisF told me that this question would not have been on topic, had it been asked on WebApps.SE.  While I believe I understand the points made on [Are API questions on topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/740/29640), I don't am unclear why this question would be considered to be a developer asking how to use Google App Engine, rather than a Google App Engine user asking how to use the site.  Campaign Monitor, for example, has a developer side (API, libraries, etc.) and a web interface, the latter being the mechanism a user would probably use if they wished to create clients with their own billing.

Part of my understanding of this distinction is based on [Where does my git question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go).

In short, I'm unclear exactly where the distinction lies between a developer asking how to use a web application and a user of that web application asking the same question.

Comment: The post you're referencing has been deleted, and only users on [programmers.se] with more than 10,000 reputation points can see it, so there's really no way for any of us to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to read the question before it got deleted and found it rather bombastic. If you would have focussed on the user part, searching for some help with a website, your post would've appeared differently. In stead (as far as I remember) you elaborated on how much money you earn and how much you could've earned.

Anybody asking a question about any web application is welcome on Web Applications.